# Range slider how to make step size change in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
 <Slider v-model="[0, 2500]" :min="0" :max="2500" :step="50" />
</template>
```

I need the steps to be like [50, 100, 250] but not the single value i.e 50
Can anybody help me with this

Comment: First of all, what slider plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `input range` with your desired values. Only the `v-model` is important to create the two-way-data-binding.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedValue: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="2500" step="50" v-model="selectedValue">
  <p>selected value: {{ selectedValue }}</p>
</div>
```